# Applying Animation to React Component while using Styled Components

Tags: animation, reactjs, onclick, styled-components

I am using a new library to create React Components, Styled-Components.

I want to apply an animation Tremble on my component via an onClick.

```
export class FormLoginTest extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function

      static propTypes = {
        isTrembling: React.PropTypes.bool
      };

      static defaultProps = {
        isTrembling: true
      };

      onMakeTremble() {
       alert("hello")

      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Form >
            <ContainerFluid>
              <H2>Login</H2>
            </ContainerFluid>
            <ContainerFluid>
              <Label htmlFor="username">Username</Label>
              <Input type="text" id="username" placeholder="bob" autoCorrect="off" autoCapitalize="off" spellCheck="false" />
            </ContainerFluid>
            <ContainerFluid>
              <Label htmlFor="password">Password</Label>
              <Input id="password" type="password" placeholder="••••••••••" />
            </ContainerFluid>
            <ContainerFluid>
              <Button nature="success" onClick={this.onMakeTremble}>Hello</Button>
            </ContainerFluid>
          </Form>
        );
      }
    }
```

So there is no Style.css sheet with Styled Components, all css is applied via javascript. Form has already been applied a css:

export class Form extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function

```
      static propTypes = {
        children: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired,
        className: React.PropTypes.string
      };
      //
      static defaultProps = {
        isTrembling: true
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <form className={this.props.className}>
            {React.Children.toArray(this.props.children)}
          </form>
        );
      }
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-class-assign
    Form = styled(Form)` 
              max-width: 800px;
              margin:0 auto;
              display: block;
              height: 100%;
              border: 1px solid grey;
              & h2{
                text-align:center;
              };
            `;

    export default Form;
```

And I have a component Tremble as well:

const shake = keyframes`
           10%, 90% {
            transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
          }

```
      20%, 80% {
        transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
      }

      30%, 50%, 70% {
        transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
      }

      40%, 60% {
        transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
      }
    `;


    const Tremble = styled.div`
      display: inline-block;
      &:hover {
        animation: ${shake} 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        perspective: 1000px;
      }
    `;


    export default Tremble;
```

Any clue as to how this may work?

Comment: Same probleme here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635239/animation-is-not-being-dynamically-assigned-to-a-styled-component/64635427#64635427

Answer (score 2):

Check out the docs under the keyframes section. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components

You might try importing keyframes from `'styled-components'` and use it like this:

**Example**

```
import styled, {keyframes} from 'styled-components';

const moveGradient = keyframes`
  0%{background-position:38% 0%}
  50%{background-position:63% 100%}
  100%{background-position:38% 0%}
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background-size: 800% 800%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(${props => props.gradientRotation}, #cc6bbb, #ffa86d);
  animation: ${moveGradient} 10s ease-out infinite;
`;
```

I am encountering a problem with keyframes myself, as this code doesnt work with my gradient animation, but it will with others.

I will link to my question/issue in a comment here later :)!