# Animation is not being dynamically assigned to a styled-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm unable to assign a CSS animation to a styled component dynamically. I've reproduced it below.

I initially was trying to define the CSS animation as,

```
. . .
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components'
. . .

export default function App() {
    . . . .
}


const slideAnimation = keyframes`
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    100% {
        translateX(-400px);
    }
`;
```

But this [threw an error](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#keyframes), which is why I am now wrapping the animation with the `css` helper.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, is assigning animations impossible this way with `styled-components`?

[image: busy-river-vtb8u]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc https://styled-components.com/docs/api#keyframes

Create animation with `keyframe` and put into a css with `css`

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-khorana-5usys